# How to calculate a service area of a facility, while using multiple co-variables?

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity, cost-path, service-area

Problem we would like to solve is finding out what methods are to calculate the most efficient routes in a map with distance/travel time, pop density and facility capacity as co-variables! Perhaps somebody with more experience knows where to find a useful tutorial?

[image]

Currently, I have been able to create a map (see image above) using:

1. Eurostat data
2. Input from a csv with consumption rates per country

As a result, consumption per capita has been mapped on NUTS2 level in the EU.
The next thing I have done was adding the different types of facilities to the maps, based on postal codes which then have been transferred by a script to the location on the maps with the projection of CRS EPSG:3035 - ETRS89 / LAEA Europe - Projected. Sidequest: I am also wondering how to add more data to these facility points.

All of this is saved as geojson, but I suspect it would be better to use rasters instead to overcome the issue. I am new to QGIS and think the network analysis tool or an approach with Python combined with the creation of some own formulas would be a way to solve it.

What I have tried before are checking out some tutorials on YouTube, however these handle very simple queries rather than the more complex one from this issue.
Also esri's documentation on [proximity analysis](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/geoprocessing/proximity_analysis.htm) or [finding a service area](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Finding%20a%20service%20area) seems to answer the question partly, however it requires integration / synthesis which currently lies outside my level experience.